# Debian 11 не загружается после временного отключения SSD диска

Tags: linux, debian

На единственном SSD диске на компе стоит Win 10. Купил еще один SSD, заменил вместо старого и  установил Debian 11(для изучения). Вернул старый SSD с Win 10 - работает. Снова заменил на новый SSD c Debian 11 не загружается.

Comment: Ну а чё пишет ?

Comment: Ну так правильно в загрузчике пропишите разделы (по меткам, например).